# Working with multiple clients/languages/sites

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

I would like to ask what a good solution to working with clients that have different websites.

My first one is how to deal with languages? Do I create separate tests? for 125 different clients? Are there tools out there that can handle different languages that can work in Java.

My second one is how to handle clients that use the same software, but their own site, so forms may change, such as fields are not present, or certain fields are required and others are optional?

Answer (score 1):

1 - There are a couple of Java libraries to deal with internationalization, as [awkay/easy-i18n](https://github.com/awkay/easy-i18n). I would recommend to take the same approach used by the SUT - libraries and code patterns.

Regarding "Do I create separate tests for 125 different clients?": You should always keep in mind the [test pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html). Depending on the kind of test you are doing, replicating each validation for 125 can be both unnecessary costly and slow down strongly the performance of your suite.

[image]

2 - If you are using the [Page Object pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html), you can reach a good level of abstraction of the different forms used by these sites and make your tests easy to maintain. Good code review practices will surely increase the quality of the architecture of your automation suite.